# Running count based on dates in 2 different columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, date, count

I have a similar df but much larger.  I am trying to keep a running count of total open positions based on dates.  The COUNTS column is based on how many open start dates there are less the end dates. Each start date and end date passed would equate to one position for each instance.

So in index position 0 to 4 the count is 1,2,3,4,5 (ie there is a new position on each date in Start column) but then in index position 5 the number in the COUNT column is still 5 because we added another position (index row 5) from the Start column but then one position was taken away because the END column in index position 4 took out a position.

Similar in index row 6 you added another position but took out a position because index row 2 END date was '2015-03-20'.  Hence one position went in and one position came out.  Then in index row 7 the COUNT column number is 6 because a new position went in and no position came out (because there were no new end dates).

I dont have any code to share because I cant figure out how to do this.  But here is an example df with what I am trying to explain

```
rng = pd.date_range('2015-03-14', periods=8, freq='D')
rng2 = ['','','2015-03-20','','2015-03-19','','2015-03-22','2015-03-23']
df100 = pd.DataFrame({ '1': rng, '2' : rng2,'3':[1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6]}) 
df100.columns = [['Start','End','COUNT']]
df100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

1. Create a group of the count of all `Start` by `End` and then merge the dataframe back on itself to figure out the value to be subtracted.
2. However, you cannot just subtract the value of that particular row from the row number. You need to subtract the cumulative sum with `.cumsum()`. Here is an example of what I mean by the previous sentence for rows 5, 6 and 7:
   The calculation should be `5-0=5`, `6-1=5`, and `7-2=5` INSTEAD OF `5-0=5`, `6-1=5`, and `7-1=6`). As you can see, the value that is being subtracted in the former is the cumulative sum of the series `s` that we created that identifies the value that should be subtracted.

---

```
rng = pd.date_range('2015-03-14', periods=8, freq='D')
rng2 = ['','','2015-03-20','','2015-03-19','','2015-03-22','2015-03-23']
df100 = pd.DataFrame({ '1': rng, '2' : rng2}) 
df100.columns = ['Start','End']
df100['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df100['Start'])
df100['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df100['End'])
In[1]:
       Start        End
0 2015-03-14        NaT
1 2015-03-15        NaT
2 2015-03-16 2015-03-20
3 2015-03-17        NaT
4 2015-03-18 2015-03-19
5 2015-03-19        NaT
6 2015-03-20 2015-03-22
7 2015-03-21 2015-03-23
```

Then, run the following code:

```
s = (pd.merge(df100,
              df100[['End']].assign(end_count=df100.groupby('End')['Start'].transform('count'))
                                                   .rename({'End':'Start'}, axis= 1)
              ,on='Start', how='left'))['end_count'].fillna(0)
df100['COUNT'] = df100.index + 1 - s.cumsum()
df100
Out[1]: 
       Start        End  COUNT
0 2015-03-14        NaT    1.0
1 2015-03-15        NaT    2.0
2 2015-03-16 2015-03-20    3.0
3 2015-03-17        NaT    4.0
4 2015-03-18 2015-03-19    5.0
5 2015-03-19        NaT    5.0
6 2015-03-20 2015-03-22    5.0
7 2015-03-21 2015-03-23    6.0
```